# Store to a specific id in a One-To-Many Polymorphic relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have the following 3 models:

Guide:

```
class Guide extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function commentable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

Game:

```
class Game extends Model
{
    public function guides(){
        return $this->morphMany(Guide::class, 'commentable')->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
    }
}
```

User:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function guides(){
        return $this->morphMany(Guide::class, 'commentable')->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
    }
}
```

And the following contoller:

GuidesContoller:

```
class GuidesContoller extends Controller
{
public function store()
    {
        $data = request()->validate([
            'game_id' => 'required',
            'title' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required',
        ]);

        $guide= auth()->user()->guides()->create($data);

        return redirect("/guide/{$guide->id}/{$guide->title}");
    }
}
```

Which gives `General error: 1 table builds has no column named game_id` due to `'game_id' => 'required'` because there is no `game_id` in the database. How would I perform this save where the signed in user selects a specific game when creating a new guide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the `game_id` column in your guides migration like so
`database/migrations/date_create_guides_table.php`

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('guides', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('game_id'); // necessary column
        $table->foreign('game_id')->references('id')->on('games')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('description');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('commentable_id'); // morphTo relationship columns
        $table->string('commentable_type');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: You can also do `$table->morphs('commentable')` instead of doing the two columns manually. It will also add the appropriate index which you are missing.

Comment: Thank you! didn't know about that

Comment: @CaddyDZ I added the 2 lines that you mentioned in my migration file and when I run a fresh migrate, I get the following error now: General error: 1005 Can't create table `laravel`.`guides` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `guides` add constraint `guides_game_id_foreign` foreign key (`game_id`) references `games` (`id`) on delete cascade) any idea why?

Comment: @Alex the foreign key data type must correspond to the local key data type, meaning that `game_id` must be defined as `bigIncrements` and another possibility is that you're trying to migrate the `guides` table before the `games` tables which throws the same error